# How to use a cells content to reference a sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project just on Excel, not using VBA. I am trying to use a [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function to count the number of times `C3` (the user types what they want to search into `C3`). I have four spreadsheets to search, the name of the spreadsheet the user wants to search is typed into `С4`. So the formula I have right now is `=Countif('C4'!A2:A550,C3)`.

This doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=INDIRECT()`

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(C4&"!A2:A550"),C3)
```

By using `INDIRECT()` you can string together the range address as a string; Excel will interpret the range address from the string you provide.

[INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)